# overloading methods where only difference is optional vs. non-optional type

Tags: swift

I was under the impression that swift can have overloaded methods that differ only in the type of object that the methods return.  I would think that I could have two funcs with the same signature yet they differ in return type.

```
import Foundation

// ambiguous use of 'IsTextEmpty(text:)'
func IsTextEmpty(text : String?) -> Bool? {
  return text?.isEmpty
}

func IsTextEmpty(text : String?) -> Bool {
   guard let text = text else {
     return true
   }

   return text.isEmpty
}

let text: String? = nil

if let empty = IsTextEmpty(text:"text") {
   print("Not Empty")
}

if IsTextEmpty(text: text) {
   print("Empty")
}
```

Here, both functions have the same input parameters but one func returns an optional `Bool?` and the other returns a `Bool`.  In this case I get an error:

```
ambiguous use of 'IsTextEmpty(text:)'
```

If I change the name of one of the input parameters I no longer get the ambiguous error:

```
// Works
func IsTextEmpty(foo : String?) -> Bool? {
  return foo?.isEmpty
}

func IsTextEmpty(text : String?) -> Bool {
   guard let text = text else {
     return true
   }

   return text.isEmpty
}

let text: String? = nil

if let empty = IsTextEmpty(foo:"text") {
   print("Not Empty")
}

if IsTextEmpty(text: text) {
   print("Empty")
}
```

Shouldn't the compiler detect that they are two distinct methods even though their return types are different, since an optional `Bool?` is a different type from a non-optional `Bool`?

Comment: In case of same method name and only return type difference, the compiler won't be able to distinguish. As  you can have `let abc = IsTextEmpty(text:"text")` for both optional return and nonoptional return. How do you think, the compiler will be able to pick out one method.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler needs some context to decide which method to call, e.g.

```
let e1 = IsTextEmpty(text: text) as Bool
let e2: Bool = IsTextEmpty(text: text)
```

to call the non-optional variant, or

```
let e3 = IsTextEmpty(text: text) as Bool?
let e4: Bool? = IsTextEmpty(text: text)
```

to call the optional variant. Now

```
if IsTextEmpty(text: text) {
    print("Empty")
}
```

compiles without problems: the if-statement requires a boolean
expression, so there is no ambiguity here.

But apparently the compiler is not smart enough to figure out that
in the context of an optional binding the  expression on the right-hand side must be *some* optional
and to infer the unwrapped type automatically.

You need to annotate the type of `empty` explicitly:

```
if let empty: Bool = IsTextEmpty(text: text) { ... }
```

or to make the return type explicit:

```
if let empty = (IsTextEmpty(text: text) as Bool?) { ... }
```

Comment: Is the inability of the compiler to infer the rhs in optional binding in this context possibly viable for a bug report? For clarity, we may study the related pattern matching and binding form (same ambiguity error), and note that `if case let .some(empty) = IsTextEmpty(text: "text") { /* ... */ }` will fail to compile if `IsTextEmpty(text:)` is a single overload which returns a non-optional (_"Error: pattern cannot match values of type '`Bool`'"_). I would expect the compiler to be able to infer usage of the only overload which is actually valid/compiles (no SFINAE-like action here? :) ).

Comment: @dfri: Yes, and `if let empty = IsTextEmpty(foo:"text")` would also fail if there is only a function returning a non-optional, so there is one one possible choice. My *guess* is that the compiler cannot resolve the RHS as "something returning an optional" without knowing the unwrapped type, but I am not familiar with the inner workings of the compiler at all. – Filing a bug report won't hurt, perhaps it can be improved, or an Apple engineer explains why it cannot be done.

Comment: Yes that guess sounds plausible. [Here are some more minimal examples](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7eff7ba0584f295464805db8161a9491) of the inferrence failure (and the non-failure when using your two workarounds above, even those both are valid also for the non-Optional return, in case this was the only overload).

Comment: @dfri: The last 2 lines compile because a non-optional can be automatically wrapped into a non-optional, as in `let s: String? = "foo"`

Comment: Maybe someone over at the swift evolution repo would know?

Comment: @user6902806: I would probably ask at swift-users first, swift-evolution is about discussing the future development of the language.

Comment: Yes I expect the last two lines two compile (for the reasons you mention): but at the same time we can observe that those last two lines are actually the only ones among the pattern matching examples (in the gist) that are valid for a `Bool` as well as a `Bool?` return. Likewise, those two are the only ones where the compiler sees no ambiguity when both overloads exists (choosing the optional overload rather than the non-optional an implicit to optional conversion). On the other hand, all the examples where the non-optional return doesn't compile yields ambiguity when attempting overload res.